# Excel table connection will only refresh if I close and reopen the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am running Excel 2010 and I have a table which is connected to a MS Access 2010 query.  I have some VBA which updates the SQL of the Access query.  Then when I refresh the Excel table the data for the specified date range is returned.

This typically works just fine.  However, a part of the monthly process is to Save As the workbook into a new folder under a new name each month.  At that point, I can no longer refresh the Excel table.  I receive the following error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   The query did not run, or the database table could not be opened.
>   Check the database server or contact your database administrator.  Make sure the external database is available and hasn't been moved or reorganized, then try the operation again.

If I close out of all my Excel workbooks and get back into the workbook in question the refresh works fine.

In order to avoid the closing and reopening I would like to identify and resolve the true cause of the error.

Some fixes that I have read about on this site and ruled out are as follows

Background Refresh
It is and always has been set to false

Database permissions 
I feel pretty confident this is not the issue because the credentials are not changed by my closing and reopening the workbook yet my ability to refresh the Excel table does change.

If anybody has any thoughts on what may be going wrong here I would greatly appreciate the assistance.  A solution involving VBA would be perfectly fine as well.

Troublesome code:

```
Sub RunQueries()

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

I will point out that I do not believe this to be a VBA issue.  Even when I try to manually refresh the table within Excel I receive the error.  Running the query from within MS Access works fine.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the Access database via Microsoft Query instead? That would allow you to use parameters directly within Excel instead of having to change anything via VBA.

Comment: I have never tried that.  I will look into doing this.  Do you think it will address my problem or is this a general process change that you are recommending?

Comment: Mostly a general process change. It does use a different method of connecting, though, so it's possible that it may fix your issue as well.

Comment: I'm thinking that the connection itself may not be the issue since it works sometimes and doesn't work other times.  I could be wrong on this though.

Comment: I have no way of proving this, but it's possible that the file is using "relative" file paths to access the database. When you save it to another location, that would mess it up. Closing and opening Excel again would reset the workbook's file path, allowing it to function again. It sounds reasonable to me, but like I said before, I have no way of proving it.

Comment: Josh, it would be helpful to see VBA code. This line concerns me: "I have some VBA which updates the SQL of the Access query." Be sure this dynamic query is effectively finished updating before running any Excel process that connects to it.

Comment: @josh -  please post your code so we can help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hi Parfait, good thought.  I'm thinking that if the problem is a result of the VBA not having sufficient time to update the MS Access query's SQL then I should be able to refresh the table after waiting a sufficient amount of time.  However, I have ruled this out because no amount of waiting allows for the table to be refreshed.  The only fix I have found thus far is to exit out of every single Excel workbook that is currently open and then re-enter the workbook in question.

Comment: PermaNoob - I had not considered the possibility of relative paths.  Could you please elaborate on this as I am not familiar with that concept.  I do explicitly direct the table to the database via a full network path and database name - as in, not a mapped drive.  Would this make a difference?